# Solr in production

Tags: java, tomcat, solr, jetty

Can Solr(version 4.6) with its default Jetty be used in Production? or Should I deploy it to Tomcat?

I found this information but not sure if it really meant for production environment?

> Solr ships with a working Jetty server, with optimized settings for
>   Solr, inside the example directory. It is recommended that you use the
>   provided Jetty server for optimal performance. If you absolutely must
>   use a different servlet container then continue to the next section on
>   how to install Solr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been using the same exact configuration Solr 4 + Jetty for the production environment of a medium sized project (1.700.000 rich documents, about 35GB of index size) and it works perfectly (scaling gracefully as well). You can try the performance yourself here http://www.ricerca-amministrativa.it (it's italian, just type "test", "pizza" or whatever in the search box). The crucial thing is to allocate enough memory to Jetty via the standard JVM params.

In that project the frontend web server is a standard Apache, proxying to Glassfish 3.x (Java EE, JSF) for dynamic stuff. Jetty is responsible only of serving Solr.

Comment: Great! Thank you. This is exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: I have a different question on the same scenario. Could you please look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391330/solr-with-jetty-on-lamp-server-admin-page-access-issue

Comment: I answered that one as well.

Comment: Which java are you using? OpenJDK? Oracle?